# Low Dialog Recording

Tags: dialogue, location-recording, location-sound, production

Hey Everyone,

I accidentally messed up two days of location audio, by my FP-33 being set to Mic Level on its outputs, instead of Line. I know that my signal to noise is now completely ruined, but is there any way to salvage any of those recordings or should I tell the director that we have to do that stuff over?

Comment: Go ahead and upload a short snippet, if possible. Otherwise we can't be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, I run the dialogue out into Analog and boost it up with an analogue preamp and then back into Pro Tools - but that's usually the mix.

YMMV on digital plug-ins for that gain staging, but I have had the most success on "unusable" low recordings by boosting it in the analogue domain as opposed to in the digital realm. In my experience, noise reduction plug-ins seem to work better this way, once the signal is boosted, so that there is more "resolution" of the waveform.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how bad the noise is you can try using RX to denoise it. It's not ideal, but you may be able to salvage something from it!

Answer (score 0):

the only way to know will be to load up some of the recordings and have a dialogue editor or mixer check them, after cranking gain to get them ot a useable level... Were you recording to a 24bit recorder?

Comment: Yeah, I was recording into an H4N, with .wav files, in 48K/24 Bit.

Comment: All of the H4n's input's are Mic Level though.